# Два Дива, один в другом

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой Div, И как после этого писать в нижней части красного дива?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вам понадобится position и z-index для решения этой задачи.

```css
.wrap {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
}
.wrap > div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.first {
    background: green;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.second {
    background: red;
    top: 90px;
    left: 90px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.text {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 19px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="text">Текст какой-то</div>
  </div>
</div>
```